# slice df where column looks like [(A, 3), (-A, 1), (-C, 4)] using criteria like all rows such that A>5 etc

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, slice

I have a dataframe that has a column that looks something like the following:

```
dct = {}
for x in range(0,1000000):
    test = {'A': np.random.randint(1,5), '-A': np.random.randint(1,5), '-C': np.random.randint(1,5)}
    dct[str(x)+'_key'] = test

df = pd.DataFrame([[d.items()] for d in dct.values()])

df.tail()
Out[208]:

    0
    1299995 [(A, 3), (-A, 1), (-C, 4)]
    1299996 [(A, 2), (-A, 4), (-C, 1)]
    1299997 [(A, 3), (-A, 1), (-C, 3)]
    1299998 [(A, 2), (-A, 2), (-C, 1)]
    1299999 [(A, 1), (-A, 2), (-C, 4)]
```

I have about 1.3 million rows in the dataframe. There are other columns but for this question they are not relevant.

In my real life situation the total sum of the count per row = 10. But I don't know how to create an example dataframe using `np.random.randint()` that satisfies that the total count per row has to equal 10. Valid alphabets are any from the following `(A,B,C,D,-A,-B,-C,-D)`.

So every row selects from that set with the restriction that total `count = 10`. So a row can have anything like:

```
[(A, 10)]
[(B, 3), (-D, 1), (-A, 6)]
[(A, 2), (B, 1), (-C, 2),(-D,5)]
```

In any case, the above example df should suffice.

What I want to do is be able to slice this df using this column using criteria that resembles questions like:

```
-all rows such that the number of A > 5 AND B < 0 (or not existent) AND -D > 2
```

The questions can be single or multi-conditions like the above.

In any case, I'm not sure how to do this efficiently, especially since each row is comprised of tuples.

Comment: Can you split the data into their own columns?  Should be easy if you can do that.

Comment: I wrote an answer assuming you cannot split the data into their own columns. If you can, it will make things easier...

Comment: one issue is each row doesn't necessarily have to have data in all columns. For example A=10 only occupies column 1 while the others are nan. Not sure if its good practice to have too many columns when not necessary? The other thing is I already have a large number of columns so I'm not sure if adding 10 more for this particular statistic is an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can split the column of tuples, this should work, just replace the conditionals with your numbers.  I used these for the example data:

```
def f(x, var):
    tup_list = list(x)
    for t in tup_list:
        if t[0] == var:
        return t[1]
    return np.NaN

df.columns = ['col']
for var in ['A', '-A', 'B', '-B', 'C', '-C', 'D', '-D']:
    df[var] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: f(x, var))

df2 = df.loc[(df['A'] > 3) & ((df['-A'] < 3) & (df['B'] is not np.NaN)) & (df['-C'] > 2)]
```

Comment: would this vectorize the split-up across the entire pattern column (6 million rows)?

Answer (score -1):

Easy, convert the column to a dictionary:

```
df[0] = df[0].apply(dict)
```

Now, whatever your query, you can write it as:

```
def query(row, key, value, cond):
    return eval(str(row.get(key)) + cond + str(value))

df.apply(query, key='A', value=2, cond='>', axis=1)
```

Or simply as:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[0].get('A') > 2, axis=1)
```